# VS can not open solution of android application

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-sdk-2.3

I can not create or open an android application project. VS tries to open the solution but it only shows a message box with "preparation of solution".

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure of what you are asking. What version of VS are you using? What you are trying to open, does it actually work?

Try giving it a little bit of time if it is getting hung up on loading.